# How to type the ’ character on Windows 10 login screen?

Tags: windows-10, login-screen

Out of stupidity, I have used the ’ character in my Windows 10 login password via copy-paste, thinking that it is either ', ` or ' and now can't login to my Windows 10 account (am using Linux Mint right now). Neither over the German, nor English keyboard setting, ’ seems to be accessible. So any idea how to type ’ on the Windows 10 login screen?

Comment: Here is a list for all ASCII Values: http://www.wendag.com/Computer/ascii_code.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution**

1. Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>
2. Press <kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>6</kbd> (on the numeric keypad)
3. Release <kbd>Alt</kbd>

**Explanation**

First, I used the [ASCII Value Tool](http://asciivalue.com/) to get the decimal value of `’`.  It is 146.

> [Inserting ASCII characters - Office Support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/insert-ascii-or-unicode-latin-based-symbols-and-characters-d13f58d3-7bcb-44a7-a4d5-972ee12e50e0?ocmsassetID=HA010167539&CorrelationId=715ce1e0-b6ec-4ce5-b66d-27579a7ce818&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#bm1)
>
> To insert an ASCII character, press and hold down ALT while typing the
>   character code. For example, to insert the degree (º) symbol, press
>   and hold down ALT while typing 0176 on the numeric keypad.

**EliteBook Specific (similar for other laptops)**

You mentioned in your comment that you have an HP EliteBook 8460 Laptop.  Like most laptops without a dedicated number pad, you can use the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key to access the number-pad keys on the right side of the keyboard.

I found this image of an HP EliteBook 8460p keyboard.

1. Hold <kbd>Fn</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>
2. Press <kbd>M</kbd>for 0, <kbd>J</kbd> for 1, <kbd>U</kbd> for 4, <kbd>O</kbd> for 6
3. Release <kbd>Fn</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>

Note: This assumes the keyboard layout below.

[image: EliteBook 8460p Keyboard]

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late answer. Your solution would probably work on most laptops, but I have a hp 8460p laptop without a numpad and it seems that it doesn't allow me to type ASCII-values in the login screen, it seems. Still gonna your accept your answer, since it answers the questions as stated in its original form :)

Comment: Of course you can!  Use the Fn key to type the numeric keyboard keys, indicated by the number inside the square on the right section of the keyboard.

Comment: Holy, you are my hero, Steven! It worked, thanks a ton :D